# Unusual behaviour of returning old variable value in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I was trying to just add some ifs in the function to complete a task in edube.org, related to taking care of the exception or safe gaurd your problem. Below is my program

```
import math

def inputValueCheck():
    
    x = input("Enter x: ")
    print('1 ',x)
    number = True #please ignore
    if x.isnumeric() is False:
        print('enter positive digits only')
        inputValueCheck()
    elif x.isnumeric() is True and int(x) < 0:
        print('enter positive digits only')
        inputValueCheck()
    else:
        print('2 ',x)
        #return x
    print('3 ',x)
    return x
    
    
x = float(inputValueCheck())
y = math.sqrt(x)

print("The square root of", x, "equals to", y)
```

```
> 1st time Input - 
Enter x: aaa, 
**output** 
-1  aaa
> enter positive digits only


> 2nd time Input - 
Enter x: 12
> **output**
    print 1  12
    print 2  12
    print 3  12
    print 3  aaa
> 
> 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 21, in
> <module>
>     x = float(inputValueCheck())   ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'aaa'
```

Why is this behaviour by Python? Why is the old value of x i.e. 'aaa' here getting returned every time and causing an exception? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Each recursive call has its own set of *local variables*

Comment: Don't use recursion to implement a simple loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run a function that:

1. doesn't return anything if the input data is invalid, and
2. re run the same function that doesn't return anything.

Just return the function instead of trying to run it again from within the same function. Also you can avoid the extra if statement by using `or` like this:

```
import math

def inputValueCheck():
    x = input("Enter x: ")
    number = True
    if x.isnumeric() is False or int(x) < 0:
        print('enter positive digits only')
        return inputValueCheck()
    else:
        return x

x = float(inputValueCheck())
y = math.sqrt(x)

print("The square root of", x, "equals to", y)
```

Also, what is the `Number = True` for?

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, It is another way of doing it and a more efficient way. But my question is why Python3 is returning a string 'aaa' when an integer '12' has been assigned to 'x'.

Comment: @Rohit You are thinking that `12` has been assigned to `x` when you gave input in the 2nd attempt. 

But here, that was assigned to a separate invocation of the function. So, the first function call's `x` still has `"aaa"` as the value. That's why you get the error. In Python, the arguments are passed as their values. Not by their reference.

Comment: awesome @Nusab19, got it. That makes sense. Thanks, a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Each recursive call has its own set of *local variables*. This is always how functions work. The only value that ever gets returned is `return x` and `x` in that scope is indeed`'aaa'`. The fact that somewhere up the call stack there is a local variable `x` with some other value doesn't matter.

So consider this simple example:

```
def foo():
    x = "foo"

def bar():
    x = "bar"
    foo()
    return x

print(bar())
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing a function without argument, it is more difficult to check the type of **x**, but if you don't want to define a function **inputValueCheck(x)**, you can always try to convert the variable to a float with an **'expect ValueError'** if it does'nt work
I also did'nt understand the usage of **'number = True'** so I made a script where it is useful :

```
import math

def inputValueCheck():    
    number = False
    while number == False:
        x = input("Enter x: ")
        try:
            x = float(x)
            if x > 0:
                print("x is a positive number")
                number = True
                return x
            else:
                print("x is not a positive number")
        except ValueError:
            print("x is not a number")

x = float(inputValueCheck()) y = math.sqrt(x)

print('The square root of', x, "equals to", y)
```

But there can be many way to do it

Comment: thanks @M4elstr0m for your answer. It is another way of doing it, may be more efficient. But my question is why Python3 is return string 'aaa' when an integer '12' has been assigned to 'x'.